# Different methods to select products with expiration date

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, database-design, database-performance

Create an expiration date, when creating a product:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE expiry_at > NOW();
```

Disable the products with a task scheduler:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = '1';
```

Select the products that were created within 30 days:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE created_at > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

In the future, products can maybe have a duration of 60 days.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these methods based on performance, expandability and more? What experiences did you have? Are there other methods?

Comment: The 3 queries do 3 different things.  What are you comparing???

Answer (score 1):

Concettually the most useful is surely

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE created_at > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

because you can change your expiration interval easily  ...

you could also use a  param  or a value store in a proper table in db or in app param or a var  for use a more easy expiration interval not coded  in sql  .. eg :

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE created_at > CURDATE() - INTERVAL @days DAY;
```